# AS3 -- Rolling Ball Game consistently showing Error #1009

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm new to this so I'm sure there is a simple solution to what's going on, but I can't figure it out to save my life.

I'm trying to create a game where you roll a ball into a hole, then your score increases and you move on to the next level. No matter what I do, when the first ball rolls into the first hole, the game chokes on itself and stops running, even though I (think) I tell it to advance to the next frame.

My code is here --

---

```
import flash.events.Event;

var accelX:Number;
var accelY:Number;
var l2=false;
var finalscore:int = 0

var fl_Accelerometer:Accelerometer = new Accelerometer();
fl_Accelerometer.addEventListener(AccelerometerEvent.UPDATE, fl_AccelerometerUpdateHandler);


function fl_AccelerometerUpdateHandler(event:AccelerometerEvent):void
{
accelX = event.accelerationX;
accelY = event.accelerationY;
}

ball1.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movecircle);


function movecircle(evt:Event){

ball1.x -= accelX*30;
ball1.y += accelY*30;

if (l2==false) {
    if (ball1.hitTestObject(right1)) {
        result1.text="Yes!";
        ball1.alpha=0;
        l2=true;}
    else if (ball1.hitTestObject(wrong1))
            {result1.text="No!";}

if(ball1.x > (stage.stageWidth-ball1.width/2)){
    ball1.x = stage.stageWidth-ball1.width/2;   }
if(ball1.x < (0+ball1.width/2)){
    ball1.x = 0+ball1.width/2;  }
if(ball1.y > (stage.stageHeight-ball1.width/2)){
   ball1.y = stage.stageHeight-ball1.width/2;   }
if(ball1.y < (0+ball1.width/2)){
    ball1.y = 0+ball1.width/2;}
}
```

}

The .fla file can be downloaded from my Dropbox here if anyone wants to take a look -- https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3610599/whirlyball.fla

Can anyone help me with this? Like I said, I'm new at this and I'm sure I'm making a lot of mistakes but I've been trying to figure this out for a week and haven't been able to.

I sincerely appreciate this in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i see what you are trying to do. The best solution is probably some refactoring to make it a little more dynamic which will solve the problem of jumping frames for each game level.

First i'll share something i learned early on and do at the beginning of every flash project - create an action layer, lock it (you never want objects accidentally put in it), put all actionscript on this layer. (Only put script on other layers if you absolutely need to)

For the code below to work, you need to do the following things:

1. Create a copy of your project. Open it, delete all frames (We'll copy over what we need)
2. Create A Layer called Actions with 4 frames, all keyframes. Lock it
3. Create A Layer called Images with 4 frames, all keyframes
4. You really only have 4 game states (intro, start screen, game, results). So we are going to copy over layers from your project to the one we just made. Use the first frame for each game state mentioned above and copy into the new project's Images layer, one for each empty keyframe. Copy All is Right Click => Select All, Right Click => Copy. Switch to Images Layer on next empty frame and, paste (Right Click => Paste In Place). For frame 3, just copy the first instance of the ball game
5. Copy the code blocks below into the corresponding action layer frame.
6. In frame 3, remove the '1' at the end of the ball object id, right object id, and wrong object id. They should now be 'ball', 'right', 'wrong'
7. In frame 3, name the question text object 'question'
8. In frame 3, open the movie clip for both the right object and wrong object and name the text object 'textfield'. (These last three changes are explained below)

Actions Frame 1:

```
stop();
var k = setTimeout(callback, 2000);

function callback():void {
  nextFrame();
};
```

Actions Frame 2

```
stop();
start.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToNextFrame);
function fl_ClickToGoToNextFrame(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    nextFrame();
}
```

Actions Frame 3

```
import flash.events.Event;

stop();
var questions = ["Enter question 1 here", "Enter question 2 here", "Enter question 3 here"];
var rightAnswers = ["Right1", "Right2", "Right3"];
var wrongAnswers = ["Wrong1", "Wrong2", "Wrong3"];
var level = 0;
setupLevel();


var accelX:Number;
var accelY:Number;
var finalscore:int = 0

var fl_Accelerometer:Accelerometer = new Accelerometer();
fl_Accelerometer.addEventListener(AccelerometerEvent.UPDATE, fl_AccelerometerUpdateHandler);



function fl_AccelerometerUpdateHandler(event:AccelerometerEvent):void
{
    accelX = event.accelerationX;
    accelY = event.accelerationY;
}

function setupLevel(){
    ball.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movecircle);

    //reset ball
    ball.x = 215;
    ball.y = 452;
    ball.alpha = 1; 

    question.text = questions[level];
    right.textfield.text= rightAnswers[level];
    wrong.textfield.text = wrongAnswers[level];
}


function movecircle(evt:Event){

    ball.x -= accelX*30;
    ball.y += accelY*30;

    if (ball.hitTestObject(right)) {
        ball.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movecircle); //prevent unwanted triggers

        result1.text="Yes!";
        ball.alpha=0;

        setTimeout(gotoNextLevel,2000)
    }
    else if (ball.hitTestObject(wrong)){
        result1.text="No!";}

    if(ball.x > (stage.stageWidth-ball.width/2)){
        ball.x = stage.stageWidth-ball.width/2; }
    if(ball.x < (0+ball.width/2)){
        ball.x = 0+ball.width/2;    }
    if(ball.y > (stage.stageHeight-ball.width/2)){
       ball.y = stage.stageHeight-ball.width/2; }
    if(ball.y < (0+ball.width/2)){
        ball.y = 0+ball.width/2;}

}

function gotoNextLevel() {
    //goto next frame and stop
    level++;
    if(level >= questions.length){
        nextFrame();
    }
    else{
        setupLevel();
    }
}
```

Action Frame 4

```
stop ();

outputScore.text = String(finalscore);
```

In a nutshell, what we did here was take all of those states for the actual game that were originally individual frames, and combine them into one frame. Then, we make the whole thing dynamic by using the arrays at the top of the actionscript for that frame to store the questions and answers. We added those textfield id's to the hole images so we could access that text and change it on a new level. We changed the ball to just 'ball' since we don't need to keep track of multiple balls now, we just have one that we keep resetting. Every time the user chooses correctly, the game resets the state and uses the next level's questions and answers. This goes on until all questions are used.

Hope this helps! (I would have posted pictures but it wont let me until i get some reputation =P )

Comment: Fair enough! I'll give it a shot and report back here with results. Thank you so much!

Comment: YES! That's it! You have no idea how much of a weight this lifted from me. Thank you!